# Use-case, class and statechart diagram examples

Tags: uml, class-diagram, use-case, statechart

I wish to learn about the diagrams mentioned in the title but on the internet one can find a lot of trash, I have seen some that contradict each other. 
Hence I wish someone experienced if they could spare a minute to direct me to reliable sources to learn the above mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[uml-diagrams.org](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/) presents examples of what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your help.